# 'OUTPUT' was not declared in this scope - ATtiny85 with Arduino Uno r3 as ISP

Tags: arduino-uno, attiny, arduinoisp

I'm trying to follow this [this](http://highlowtech.org/?p=1695) tutorial to program an ATtiny85 micro-controller using my Arduino Uno r3 as the ISP.

I am up to the final step on the tutorial, but get an error when attempting to compile my sketch:

```
'OUTPUT' was not declared in this scope
```

I have tried multiple "Blink" scripts, but none have seemed to work.

My full error log:

```
Blink.ino:10:21: error: Arduino.h: No such file or directory
Blink.ino: In function 'void setup()':
Blink:15: error: 'OUTPUT' was not declared in this scope
Blink:15: error: 'pinMode' was not declared in this scope
Blink.ino: In function 'void loop()':
Blink:20: error: 'HIGH' was not declared in this scope
Blink:20: error: 'digitalWrite' was not declared in this scope
Blink:21: error: 'delay' was not declared in this scope
Blink:22: error: 'LOW' was not declared in this scope
```

I have also tried including Arduino.h, no help, and changing "OUTPUT" to "0x01", as it is defined to said value in Arduino.h, but instead got this error:

```
error: 'pinMode' was not declared in this scope
```

Any ideas as to what is happening?

Comment: If you change the board back to Arduino UNO does it compile? Could you turn on verbose mode for compilation and post the text that appears when you compile.

Comment: It looks like the Arduino core libraries aren't being included...

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the Arduino IDE? Seems similar to (this problem](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=82220.0), but in reverse.

Comment: The first issue, the 'missing' .h file, creates the others. Fix the INCLUDE path and the other errors will go away.

Comment: Check this thread
http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3642/output-was-not-declared-in-this-scope-attiny85-with-arduino-uno-r3-as-isp

Comment: The tutorial you are using refers to the Arduino IDE version **1.0**, are you sure you are using the same IDE version?

Answer (score 3):

Create an Arduino.h in ...\Arduino\hardware\attiny45_85\cores\attiny45_85 containing

```
#include <WProgram.h>
```

From here
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/87328/arduino-as-isp-for-attiny

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the "Cores" folder from the avi directory to the attiny director. The path was wrong for me and I was getting the same error. Had the same issue with the bootloader file. Moved it out of the avi folder as well and all worked ok then.